# Importing CSV to postgreSQL while skipping duplicates

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am a total Python (and coding) beginner, so this may be ugly.

I have a CSV file that I want to import to my postgresSQL DB.  The CSV has tons of duplicates that I don't want.  I believe I am reading the CSV fine, and adding to the DB fine, but I am having trouble with skipping duplicates.  Every time I run the below code, I insert one line, then it fails.

I'm only looking at the key at the moment, but once this works there's a whole load of other columns too which will presumably not be a problem to add [...]

```
# Setup

import csv
import psycopg2


# Read a value from the CSV to see if it's in dbItems

with open('meh_0.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)

    connection = psycopg2.connect("host=localhost dbname=postgres user=postgres port=5433 password=removed")
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT handid FROM handlist')
    dbItems = cursor.fetchall()

    print(dbItems)

    for i in range(0, 200):
        rowKey = next(reader)
        print('rowKey[0] is: ' + rowKey[0])

        found = False
        for row in dbItems:
            for element in row:
                if element == int(rowKey[0]):
                    found = True
                    break

            if found:
                break


# Then either add to the DB or skip

        if not found:
            print(rowKey[0] + ' NOT found in dbItems\n')
            sqlCommand = 'INSERT INTO handlist VALUES (' + rowKey[0] + ')'
            cursor.execute(sqlCommand)
            connection.commit()

        else:
            print(rowKey[0] + ' is found in dbItems\n')
```

I've probably moved some stuff into my 'while' loop that doesn't need to be there, I was trying to see what that changed.  Oh, and range max of 200 is arbitrary, the CSV files are huge.

The error:

```
rowKey[0] is: 34756717
34756717 is found in dbItems

rowKey[0] is: 34756717
34756717 is found in dbItems

rowKey[0] is: 34756717
34756717 is found in dbItems

rowKey[0] is: 34756718
34756718 NOT found in dbItems

rowKey[0] is: 34756718
34756718 NOT found in dbItems

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python/MyPythonScripts/RIO r5.py", line 40, in <module>
    cursor.execute(sqlCommand)
psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "handlist_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (handid)=(34756718) already exists.

>>>
```

So it's skipping all the keys I added when I've run it before, adds the new one, but then doesn't skip the new one when it iterates the loop.

Mostly, I'd like to know why it doesn't work.  But I imagine there're lots of easier ways to do this too, I'm perfectly happy to copy those if need be.

Comment: You have pre-existing rows in the db, and your csv includes the key for each csv row, and some rows in the csv are duplicates of pre-existing data and have the same key, is that right?

Comment: That's right.  Perhaps this helps, it's what's in the database right now, at least as far as the code knows:

```>>> dbItems
[(123,), (234,), (34756712,), (34756713,), (34756714,), (34756715,), (34756716,), (34756717,), (34756718,), (34756719,), (34756720,), (34756721,), (34756722,), (34756723,)]```


While rowKey is:

```>>> rowKey
['34756724', '83', '63', '32801031', '3', '6', '1', '\\N', '34620923', '29/05/2019 12:08', '0', '30545092', '29/05/2019 12:08', '\\N', '0', '34756708', '75', '10/09/2019 14:47', '\\N', 'O', '50', '25', '1', '50', 'pot']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the existing keys to a [set](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set), then check if the key from the csv row is a member of the set.  The cost of checking set membership is independent of the size of the set, so a set is a good data structure to use here.  If the csv key is in the set we move to the next row, otherwise we add the row to the database and add the key to the set.

```
# Setup

import csv
import psycopg2


# Read a value from the CSV to see if it's in dbItems

with open('meh_0.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)

    connection = psycopg2.connect("host=localhost dbname=postgres user=postgres port=5433 password=removed")
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT handid FROM handlist')
    dbItems = cursor.fetchall()

    # Build a set of existing keys
    existing = {k for k, in dbItems}


    for i in range(0, 200):
        rowKey = next(reader)
        print('rowKey[0] is: ' + rowKey[0])

        # Database keys are ints, csv values are strings...
        candidate = int(rowKey[0])

        if candidate in existing:
            # back to the top of the for loop
            continue

        # Add to the DB

        # Use the recommended way of building queries
        # https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries
        sqlCommand = 'INSERT INTO handlist VALUES (%s)'
        cursor.execute(sqlCommand, (candidate,))
        connection.commit()

        # Add our key to the set
        existing.add(candidate)
```

Comment: That works - my account is too new to display an upvote, but thanks.  The different data types were definitely confusing me, and I can't say I understand the set, but that's something new to look up.

What does the %s do when you create the SQL command?  I don't think that part worked for me.  I changed it to include rowKey[0], and dbItems now includes all the keys, but perhaps I didn't need to?

Comment: The `%s` and the corresponding second parameter to `cursor.execute` is used to ensure that values being put into the SQL statement are properly quoted according to their datatype.  This ensures for example `2020-04-27` is interpreted as a date not an arithmetic expression, and more importantly `;DELETE FROM mytable;` is interpreted as a string and not an SQL expression (AKA "SQL injection").  The link in the comment above the `sqlCommand =` line explain how to use query parameterisation in psycopg2 and the dangers of SQL injection.

Comment: You might reasonably contend that only you will use your script, so SQL injection isn't a risk.  Nevertheless, it's good to start using query parameterisation from the first, so that if you ever are working on a user-facing application you do the right thing without thinking about it, and can spot the issue in other people's code.  [Obligatory xkcd reference](https://xkcd.com/327/).  An example from [twitter today](https://twitter.com/IanColdwater/status/1254883868986892288).